# Sorting an array of integers

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a problem with my homework. I have to sort numbers in an array, from lowest to highest number. This is the code:
[Source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpYix.png)

I do have to use a function in this example, but I don't know how I can get rid of the error. I hope you can help me!

Comment: 1) change `int myArray = new string[5]` to just `int[] myArray`. 2) you'll need to look at your logic within the main method again as it's not correct. 3) next time please don't post images but rather the source code itself within your post.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't have to use a function in order to do this you could use something like this:

```
using System;
namespace Stackoverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] myArr = { 5, 17, 23, 9, 8, 10 };
            Array.Sort(myArr);
        }
    }
}
```

If you have to use a function however I would use something like this:

```
using System;
namespace Stackoverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] myArr = { 5, 17, 23, 9, 8, 10 };
            ReturnSorted(myArr);
        }

        public static int[] ReturnSorted(int[] secondArr)
        {
            int[] sorted = new int[secondArr.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < secondArr.Length; i++)
            {
                sorted[i] = secondArr[i];
            }
            Array.Sort(sorted);
            return sorted;
        }
    }
}
```

You could empty the array "secondArr" in the function using: "`Array.Clear(secondArr, 0, secondArr.Length);`" inorder to save memory.

i hope I could help!  :D

Comment: *ReturnSorted* also modifies the original array

Comment: If im not wrong "int[] sorted = secondArr;" is saving the entire first array to another one which is being sorted so the first one isnt touched.

Comment: `If im not wrong` sorry but you are. it is a *reference* assigment

Comment: You were right. I changed the code. I went around this problem with a rather ugly solution. How would you go about avoiding references?

Comment: for ex, `Array.Copy` or  using linq `var arr2 = arr1.ToArray()` And also this is posiible `var sorted=unsortedArr.OrderBy(x=>x).ToArray()`

Comment: ok. thanks i never had to deal with this kind of thing. but nice 2 know..

Comment: And finally, a one liner `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", myArr.OrderBy(x => x)));`

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    static void sortieren (int[] myArr)
    {
        Array.Sort(myArr);      
    }   
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] myArr= new int[5] {1,5,3,8,21};
        sortieren(myArr);
        foreach (int u in myArr)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(u);   
            }                
    }   
}
```

[The running code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mZiUn2)

Comment: Glad I helped you.If you have any problem write.